# Improve load time for a html page with flash

Tags: html, flash

I have a basic html page and a big flash file I need to embed. I would like to allow the user to click on the links until the flash files loads.

I was thinking of two ways to do this
1. use an iframe and put the flash file in there
2. use jquery to load and append the flash file to an internal div

Is this the way to go ? Are there better solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that jQuery is the best way to add the element to the page.

There are many plugins for jQuery which make it easy to achieve. One of the better ones I have found can be found at http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/